# How does "would" work

Tags: modal-verbs

How does "would" work in this sentence?

A: Is it "may I know who you are ?" or "may I know who are you?"?
Thanks!

B: The first one is correct. 'May I know who are you?' is not correct in standard British English; instead, it **would** be 'may I know who you are?'.

Comment: would ==> should

Comment: You can think of it like a hypothetical.  "If you said this, it would be ..."